# Continuously differentiable function with a positive infimum

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$   be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose $\delta=\inf\,\{f^{\prime}(x):\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}\gt 0 $ . Prove that $f(a)=0$   for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$   .

Answer (score 0):

By the mean value theorem, we have

for each $x>0$, there exists a $c\in (0,x)$ such that

$f(x)=xf'(c)+f(0)\geq x\delta +f(0)$

Since we have $f'(c)\geq\delta$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $f(x)>0$ for some $x>0$.

Indeed, simply choose large enough $x$.

Likewise, we also have by the mean value theorem for each $x<0$

$f(x)=f'(c)x+f(0)$ for some $c\in (x,0)$

Again, since $f'(c)\geq\delta>0$, we can choose a sufficiently "negative" $x\in (-\infty,0)$ such that $f(x)<0$

Now since $f(x)>0$ for some x and also $f(x)<0$ for some other x, we have by the intermediate value theorem, that $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.